# How to pass encrypted password from jenkins to gradle?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-plugins, gradle-plugin

I am passing multiple parameters to a grade task from jenkins and want to pass username and password as well.

-PUsername="abc_${ENVIRONMENT}" -PPassword=? -PEnv=${ENVIRONMENT} MyGradleTask

The username is dynamic based on the environment selected (ex: abc_DEV) and this username has an encrypted password in build environment. I was able to run this in batch and set password as below and this works.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set Username=abc_%ENVIRONMENT%
call set "Password=!Username!"
call batchFile.bat
```

But how do I pass encrypted password like above from jenkins to gradle?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using traditional Jenkins jobs, then you can pass password also like any other variable.

If you are using jenkinsfile, then you can use WithCredentials function.
eg.
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: '',
usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {

sh 'echo uname=$USERNAME pwd=$PASSWORD'
 }